# Client side validation for my dropdown populated with enum values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view where I use a dropdown list with enum:

```
public enum MaterialWorthEnumViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "")] Undefined,
    [Display(Name = "< 1.000€")] LessThan1000,
    [Display(Name = "1.000€ < 10.000€")] Between1000And10000,
    [Display(Name = "10.000€ < 100.000€")] Between10000And100000,
    [Display(Name = "100.000€ < 25.000.000€")] Between100000And25000000,
    [Display(Name = "> 25.000.000€")] GreaterThan250000000,
}
```

I use a view model with this view:

```
public class MaterialEditNewViewModel
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    ...
    [EnumRequired]
    public MaterialWorthEnumViewModel MaterialWorth { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see above, I used a custom validation [EnumRequired] I grab the code from a blog online.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EnumRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute    
{
    private const string UNDEFINED_VALUE = "Undefined";
    public string UndefinedValue { get; set; }

    public EnumRequiredAttribute() : this(UNDEFINED_VALUE)        
    {        }

    public EnumRequiredAttribute(string undefinedValue) : base()        
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(undefinedValue))            
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("undefinedValue");            
        }

        UndefinedValue = undefinedValue;        
    }         

    public override bool IsValid(object value)        
    {            
        if (value == null)            
        {                
            return false;            
        }             

        var undefined = Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), UndefinedValue);             
        return !Enum.Equals(value, undefined);        
    }    
}
```

Below is for the client side validation

```
public class ModelClientValidationEnumRequiredRule : ModelClientValidationRule 
{
    public ModelClientValidationEnumRequiredRule(string errorMessage, string undefinedValue) 
    { 
        base.ErrorMessage = errorMessage; 
        base.ValidationType = "enumrequired";
        base.ValidationParameters.Add("undefinedvalue", undefinedValue); 
    } 
}

public class EnumRequiredAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<EnumRequiredAttribute> 
{ 
    public EnumRequiredAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, EnumRequiredAttribute attribute) 
        : base(metadata, context, attribute) 
    { } 

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules() 
    { 
        return new ModelClientValidationEnumRequiredRule[] 
        { 
            new ModelClientValidationEnumRequiredRule(base.ErrorMessage, Attribute.UndefinedValue) 
        }; 
    } 
}
```

Below is the javascript for the client side validation

```
Sys.Mvc.ValidatorRegistry.validators.enumrequired = function (rule) {
    var undefinedValue = rule.ValidationParameters.undefinedvalue;
    return function (value, context) {
        return value != undefinedValue;
    }
}
```

I also updated my GLobal.asax file:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(EnumRequiredAttribute), typeof(EnumRequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

The validation works pretty well on the server side but **the client side validation is never triggered.** So when I didn't choose any value on my view for my dropdown enum, I reach the action in the controller and then the server side validation occured and I go back to the view. I concluded that the client side validation didn't occurred.

Does someone can help me doing valid client side validation for this dropdown enum ?

Thanks. I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any relationship between your `EnumRequiredAttribute` and the other 2 classes. If you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 you need to associate your custom validation attribute with the adapter. This could be done in `Application_Start`:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(EnumRequiredAttribute), 
    typeof(EnumRequiredAttributeAdapter)
);
```

Also on your client side you have shown some js code that relies on `Microsoft*.js` libraries. Those are now obsolete and should no longer be used. The default standard in ASP.NET MVC 3 for client side validation is the jquery.validate plugin.

So let's take an example.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [EnumRequired]
    public MaterialWorthEnumViewModel MaterialWorth { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View (`Index.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/enumrequiredadapter.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MaterialWorth)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MaterialWorth)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MaterialWorth)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and finally the `enumrequiredadapter.js` adapter:

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('enumrequired', ['undefinedvalue'], function (options) {
        options.rules['enumrequired'] = options.params;
        if (options.message != null) {
            options.messages['enumrequired'] = options.message;
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod('enumrequired', function (value, element, params) {
        return value != params.undefinedvalue;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Also don't forget to remove all traces of `Microsoft*.js` script references from your site. And that's pretty much it.

Comment: It works pretty well, even for client validation :) Thank you very much.